# How to make API call in Flask?

Tags: flask, python-requests

I am trying to make request to Clash of Clan Api and after requesting the right data it returns 200 ok  & if i search wrong data it returns 404 not found. How to flash message after the data is not found according to the HTTP response from the API?

my views in flask

```
@app.route('/player', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def player():
     headers = header
     url = ('https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/{}')
     query = request.form.get('search')
     player_id = urllib.parse.quote(query)
     stats = requests.get(url.format(player_id), headers=headers).json()
     return render_template('player.html', stats=stats, data=stats['achievements'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stats = requests.get(url.format(player_id), headers=headers).json()
```

Here, you just take the JSON from the body and discard a bunch of useful data. Instead,

```
response = requests.get(url.format(player_id), headers=headers)

stats = response.json()
status_code = response.status_code
success = response.ok
# ...
```

You can see all the things you can get from the `Response` object in [API documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response).